# Spring boot: can not read object list from yaml

Tags: spring, yaml

I have custom.yaml file with content:

```
refill-interval-millis: 1000

endpoints:
  - path: /account/all
    rate-limit: 10
  - path: /account/create
    rate-limit: 20
```

and my class to read that file:

```
@Component
@PropertySource("classpath:custom.yaml")
@ConfigurationProperties
public class Properties {

    private int refillIntervalMillis;
    private List<Endpoint> endpoints = new ArrayList<>();

    // getters/setters

    public static class Endpoint {
        private String path;
        private int rateLimit;

        // getters/setters
    }
}
```

So, when I run my code, `refillIntervalMillis` is set properly, but `endpoints` list is empty. Can not get why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use @PropertySource directly for YAML-files: [YAML Shortcomings](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-multi-profile-yaml)

You have 2 simple options:

use application.yml and Spring Boot loads if by default (and you can use `application-xxx.yml` and set `@ActiveProfiles(value = "xxx")`;

load YAML-file manually:

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer properties() {
    var propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    var yamlPropertiesFactoryBean = new YamlPropertiesFactoryBean();
    yamlPropertiesFactoryBean.setResources(new ClassPathResource("custom.yaml"));
    propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.setProperties(yamlPropertiesFactoryBean.getObject());
    return propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
}
```